# my child bangs on keyboard, locked windows vista doesn't seem to prevent chaos?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

So when I always lock my computer when I am away, b/c my child likes to bang on the keyboard.

The strange thing is, when I unlock the screen, I have 10's of windows open and who knows what applications started/stopped.

Isn't locking the system suppose to prevent this?

I can't believe such a basic and IMPORTANT feature messed up like this.

(albeit Microsoft probably hasn't tested the feature as well as a 3 year old can!)

Comment: What kind of windows/applications have been opened - can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have "media keys", on your keyboard?

Lock is supposed to prevent activity from the keyboard, and it sure works for the regular keys. However, it's possible that some media keys are launching some programs, and possibly go behind this lock. On laptops for example, media keys are often acting on a lower level than the operating system, so it could cause such things.

This is mostly a wild guess, of course. But I don't really see another reason for that to happen.

Comment: +1 I always thought that media keys are a combination of other normal keys. Your answer shed some light on some extraordinary behavior of this keys.